# How come props doesn't show when I try to print in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to transfer a simple class to print but it isn't working.

When I check `console.log` get something like:
`Object { "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element), type: Category(), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, _owner: {…}, _store: {…}, … }`

This is my current return on the App class as a test:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Category category = {<Category categoryId={123} categoryName="Hohnny" />} />
  </div>
);
```

And this is my category class:

```
import React from "react";

class Category extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.category);
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.categoryId}
        </div>
    ); // end return
  }
}

export default Category;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending prop in wrong way. Sending props in react is like calling a component and passing properties to it but not like passing a component to the component and expecting properties to be available.

This is how you have to call a component and pass properties to it

```
return (
     <div>
      <Category categoryId={123} categoryName="Hohnny" />
  </div>
)
```

Edit:

If you want to pass a component as prop then that can be passed like

```
<Category categoryId={123} categoryName="Hohnny" category={<SomeOtherComponent />}/>
```

Comment: so to extend the question if i have an array and I am pushing the array in is this format correct? `categories.push(<Category categoryId={data.categories[index].id}
                      categoryName={data.categories[index].name} />)`

Comment: Yeah that's valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is printed in `console.log`:

```
category = {<Category categoryId={123} categoryName="Hohnny" />}
```

You are basically passing the whole component as a prop. That is not the right way to do that. Simple example:

```
<MyComponent />
```

You want to pass props:

```
{
  someString: 'my string',
  someInt: 42,
  boolenTrue: true,
  booleanFalse: false,
}
```

What you want to do:

`<MyComponent someString="my string" someInt={42} boolenTrue booleanFalse={false} />`

Your code should look like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Category categoryId={123} categoryName="Hohnny" />
  </div>
)
```